# c# multiple chart error

Tags: c#, mysql, charts

I want to create a column chart in c#.

this is the code that i uset for that:

```
private void Vizualizare_profil()
        {
            myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `gomoku`.`informatii` WHERE `id_utilizator` = '" + id_client.ToString() + "';", myConn);
            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdap = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            myConn.Open();
            dataAdap.Fill(ds);
            myConn.Close();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Nume");
            dt.Columns.Add("Meciuri castigate");
            dt.Columns.Add("Meciuri pierdute");
            dt.Columns.Add("Meciuri remize");

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                label28.Text = Username;
                label29.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["nume"].ToString();
                label30.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["prenume"].ToString();
                label31.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["varsta"].ToString();
                label32.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["adresa_email"].ToString();

                dt.Rows.Clear();

                dt.Rows.Add("Meciuri castigate " + Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["meciuri_castigate"]), ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["meciuri_castigate"], 0 , 0);
                dt.Rows.Add("Meciuri pierdute " + Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["meciuri_pierdute"]), 0, ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["meciuri_pierdute"], 0);
                dt.Rows.Add("Meciuri remize " + Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["meciuri_remiza"]), 0, 0,ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["meciuri_remiza"]);

                chart1.DataSource = dt;
                chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Nume";
                chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Meciuri castigate";

                chart1.Series[1].XValueMember = "Nume";
                chart1.Series[1].YValueMembers = "Meciuri pierdute";

                chart1.Series[2].XValueMember = "Nume";
                chart1.Series[2].YValueMembers = "Meciuri remize";
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Database error!");
        }
```

It creates perfect the first chart but if this method is called again it shows the same data.

What is the problem and what can by done?

Comment: why would it not show the same data?. unless i am missing something. all of your variables are local to this method.

Comment: the data are depending of id_client. I checked and the data returned from the query is diferent ds(DataSet) is changeing and dt(DataTable) if formed correct

Comment: I find a solution. I added this lines of code and it worked: <pre>chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
     chart1.Series[1].Points.Clear();
     chart1.Series[2].Points.Clear(); <code>